# Command to find ARM GCC Port

Tags: gcc, arm, command-line-interface, gnu, directive

I'm really new to understanding the GNU GCC ARM compiler. I need to find the correct ARM compiler type (CM4F, CM0, et cetera). I know it depends on the target, but for the simplicity of this question I am just using an existing example. I'd really like to see if there was a command line solution, or compiler directive to find out exactly which one is needed. However, I'm using verbose, and instead I'm just getting "arm-none-eabi" which I'm not sure why, as for the sample application, it is the CM4F. How would I find this out, if I didn't already know the answer was CM4F? Thanks in advance!

What I've already tried:

The verbose compiler command/directive (I apologize, I'm not always good with precise technical definitions).

Looking at the GNU GCC ARM documentation (online, quick search)

Comment: CM0 and CM4F are not compiler types but arm products cortex-m0, cortex-m4.  The marketing names for products you (well corporations) can buy from ARM.   You are on the right path looking at arm documentation as far as the instruction sets, but the short answer is -mcpu on the arm-none-eabi command line and then more options if you want floating point.

Comment: If you want floating point for the cortex-m4 then -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 otherwise -mcpu=cortex-m4.   Cortex-m0 then -mcpu=cortex-m0 (it has not floating point).  Use these for all three parts of the toolchain gcc, assembler and linker.

Answer (score 1):

The `arm` target for GCC includes all supported 32-bit ARM architectures and CPUs.  You select the desired one when compiling your program, using the `-march`/`-mcpu`/`-mtune` options.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/ARM-Options.html for details.  The lists of architectures and CPUs is found under the `-march` and `-mtune` options respectively.

So for example, if you want to compile code that only needs to run on a Cortex M4, you can use `-mcpu=cortex-m4`.  If you want backward compatibility with ARMv6 but best performance on Cortex M0, use `-march=armv6 -mtune=cortex-m0`.